# How to add attributes to a custom table?

Tags: model, customer-attribute, install-script, frontend-model

I would like to add some attributes to a custom table with an install script.
But whatever I try it didn't work.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute(custom_data, 'street', array( ... )
```

Magento just showed my an error page that this model doesn't exist.
But I have this table in my database.
What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->getConnection()->addColumn(
    $installer->getTable('custom_data'),
    'street',
    "VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually opt to use the following method in installation scripts. It's much easier and you don't need to know the resource setup methods. It works on all types of Magento tables.

// To add a custom column to the quote item table

```
 $quoteTable = $this->getTable('sales/quote_item');

$this->run(
    "ALTER TABLE `$quoteTable` ADD test DECIMAL(12,4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Test';
);
```